# Web component grid layout system with rows and containers?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, polymer, grid-layout, web-component

Is there a grid layout system with rows and containers which is useable as a web component?

I would like to build a website with polymer but I would like to use a grid system, which collapses on small screen sizes like this: 
http://www.bootply.com/4CJ9GOYEuH

Answer (score 0):

The default flex layout has worked well enough for me for this exact purpose. Take a look at this, it should explain everything you need to know:

http://plnkr.co/edit/xIARqr?p=preview

e.g. for your situation, use this example:

```
<div class="horizontal layout">
 <div class="flex-3"><p>flex three</p></div>
 <div class="flex"><p>flex</p></div>
 <div class="flex-2"><p>flex two</p></div>
</div>
```